# In jquery add class of 'enabled' to a button if a checkbox is checked otherwise leave button as 'disabled'

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form with a bunch of checkboxes. There's an "approve" button at the bottom. What I want to do is have the button disabled as default (easy enough), but if a checkbox is checked, ad an 'enabled class' to it (also fairly easy). But say there's 3 things checked in the options, and the user clicks one of them (so that there's now 2 selected), how do I keep the button enabled?

Sorry for the newb question, I'm just getting back into development after doing design stuff for a long while.

Check the screen shot (this is using data tables).

[image] I also have a function called checkbox handler which handles the grouping of selected checkboxes and sends them to a service. $('.campaign-order-approval') is the class for the checkbox. Thanks

```
 $approveCampaign.on("click",function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
    var orderIDs = checkboxHandler();
    var params = 'order_ids=' + orderIDs;
    aep.utils.makeProxyCall('campaigns/' + actionSettings.id + '/approveOrders/approve',checkboxHandler, checkboxHandler, 'POST', params);

                      callInProgress();
                      //utils.aeAlert($l(14012));
                      return false;

                });
 function checkboxHandler () {
            var checkboxes = [];
            $('.campaign-order-approval').each(function () {
               var $this = $(this);
               if ($this.is(':checked')) {
                checkboxes.push($(this).attr('rel'));
                }
            });
            var checkboxIDS = checkboxes.join(',');
            return checkboxIDS;

           };
```

Comment: This doesn't look like the relevant code

Answer (score 1):

Add an event handler for your checkboxes onclick event:

```
$('.campaign-order-approval').on('click', function () {
    $('.campaign-order-approval').each(function() {
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
            // If any boxes are checked, add the class and return.
            $('#SubmitButton').addClass('enabled');
            return;
        }
    });
    // Otherwise nothing is checked so remove the class.
    $('#SubmitButton').removeClass('enabled');
});
```

Comment: No luck unfortunately :(. Thank you though. Just not doing anything on the button classes.

Comment: thanks Luke, but i couldn't get it to this work this way

Comment: That's ok - there are better answers here anyway. Besides, my example had a syntax error and presumed all you wanted to do was add/remove css class enabled on the button and that the button had an ID of SubmitButton.

Comment: thanks it's ok. i noticed that and fixed it - but no, it seems your code should work in theory.

Answer (score 1):

Hello if you want enable your button if two checkbox is checked.
do it if your checkbox not add checked attribute on click then add first.

```
         $('.campaign-order-approval').on('click', function() {
                var tempLen = $('.campaign-order-approval').length;
                var counter = 0;
                for (var i = 0; i < tempLen; i++) {
                    if ($('.campaign-order-approval input[type="checkbox"]').eq(i).attr("checked")) {
                        counter++;
                    }
                    if (counter >= 2) {
                        //counter = 0;
                        $('#SubmitButton').addClass('enabled');
                        //return;
                    }else{
                        $('#SubmitButton').removeClass('enabled');
                    }
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you're over complicating this.  Why not bind to the checkboxes, and let them drive whether or not the button is disabled.  When the button is clicked, get the ids.

```js
$('div').on('click', '.campaign-order-approval', function() {
  var status = 'disabled';
  if ($(this).parent().find(':checked').length > 0) {
    status = 'enabled';
  }

  //I'm not sure how you're disabling it with just the class, 
  //but for the demo I'll continue disabling it via javascript
  $('#approveCampaign').removeClass('disabled enabled')
                       .addClass(status)
                       .attr('disabled', status === 'disabled');
});

$('#approveCampaignButtons').on('click', '#approveCampaign', function() {
  var approved = $('.campaign-order-approval:checked');
  var ids = $.map(approved, function(val, index) {
return $(val).attr('rel');
  });
  alert(ids);
});
```

```css
.disabled {
  color: red;
}

.enabled {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <input rel='cb1' type='checkbox' class='campaign-order-approval'>cb1</input>
  <input rel='cb2' type='checkbox' class='campaign-order-approval'>cb2</input>
  <input rel='cb3' type='checkbox' class='campaign-order-approval'>cb3</input>
  <input rel='cb4' type='checkbox' class='campaign-order-approval'>cb4</input>
  <input rel='cb5' type='checkbox' class='campaign-order-approval'>cb5</input>
  <input rel='cb6' type='checkbox' class='campaign-order-approval'>cb6</input>
</div>

<div id="approveCampaignButtons">
  <button id="approveCampaign" disabled='true' class='disabled'>Approve</button>
  <button id="cancelCampaign">Cancel</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks - this looks so easy and clean to implement but having no luck on my end :/. these are my buttons

<div id="approveCampaignButtons">
  <button id="approveCampaign"><?=l(113)?></button>
  <button id="cancelCampaign"><?=l(63)?></button>
 </div>

Comment: @erics15 I've updated the snippet to include the html you provided.

Comment: thank you kevin - just one thing. basically how we enable buttons and disable them is through a class 'enabled' or 'disabled'. you can do something like hasClass right ? ( instead of attribute). I guess by default the button should be disabled. thanks and sorry to drag this out.

Comment: @erics15 Ah, yes, you mentioned that in the comment which is what should have been done from the beginning.  I'm not sure how  you're disabling it with just a class, so for demos sake, it's still using javascript; but the appropriate classes are still being applied for you.

Comment: hey kevin, thanks - this almost works! basically how we're disabling css is with a color and an 'unclickable' area. The only thing that it's doing is not respecting the other checkboxes when you click one of them off. so if 3 are clicked and you unclick 1 of them the button is disabled again. i owe you a beer, haha. Yours works perfectly. Can't figure out why mine doesn't

Comment: Also, this is an ajax call pulling in those results with checkboxes. not sure if that makes any difference in the event handling.

Comment: Lets move this to a chat.  Go ahead an add any additional comments in http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108668/chatting-with-eric5